# Outlook External Application/Service Start

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Is there any way to have outlook start an external application or service based on an outlook calendar task, event, appointment? Also if so, is there a way to get it to pass parameters to it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this using the Shell method.

```
Private Sub TestAcrobatReader()

    Const strcProgramName As String = _
        "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
    Const strcFilePath As String = _
        "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\plug_ins\" _
        & "Annotations\Stamps\Words.pdf"

    Dim dblProgTaskID As Double
    Dim strPathName As String

    strPathName = strcProgramName & " " & strcFilePath
    dblProgTaskID = Shell(strPathName, vbMaximizedFocus)
    MsgBox "Program Task ID:  " & dblProgTaskID

End Sub
```

Code borrowed from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3a3d1a7-5c9a-4c91-ab96-41d367eac2fb/using-shell-function-in-vba-how-do-i-pass-a-parameter). You can pass additional parameters by concatenating them on the strPathName.

For automating based on Outlook Calendar there is a wealth of information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155701%28office.10%29.aspx).